# Copy installation files that Novell Application Launcher uses

Tags: installation

I'm on a network where each workstation has some Novell software installed, including the [Novell Application Launcher](http://support.novell.com/techcenter/articles/dnd19970903.html). The Novell application launcher uses specially crafted files that are stored on a public network server. When the user double clicks an icon from the Novell Application Launcher, it somehow generates and runs the installer for that application.

I was wondering if there was any way to retrieve the actual installer for the program, so I can store it on external media, and so I don't require the Novell suite to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Not from the Zenworks snapshot.  There is a tool that watches the install process, for file and registry and whatnot changes, records them, so they can be replayed.

This obviates the need for the installer.  Also, it allows the install, customization of the application internally, all in one fell swoop.

Between versions of Zenworks the application changed, and now they use Installshields Admin Studio to watch an installer, and make an MSI instead of one of these snapshot based things, but that is the closest you will get.

I do not think the migration tool from Zenworks 7.x to Zenworks Configuration Management 10.x supports converting snapshots to MSI files.  But they might add it one day.